# Why is my thread local bound database context not being found in request life-cycle methods?

Tags: python, database, flask, connection

I have a simple Flask application where I use the before and after request lifecycle methods to create and close database connections from a pool. I have a `db_context` factory which dependency-wise I propagate downstream to my service application layer to obtain instances of the current `db_context` from where to run database operations.

I can see that the thread IDs for the before and after request lifecycle functions. However, the `db_context` I am storing under the threading local isn't available between these calls. Why? Please find a minimal excerpt of the code below:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, request
import threading

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

TL_DB_CONTEXT_KEY = 'db_context'

def db_context_factory():
    """
    Creates or retrieves a thread-local-bound db_context

    Returns:
        db_context instance
    """
    # check whether a `db_context` is already available
    thread_local = threading.local()
    db_context = getattr(thread_local, TL_DB_CONTEXT_KEY, None)
    if db_context is None:
        db_context = ... initialize database
        setattr(thread_local, TL_DB_CONTEXT_KEY, db_context)
    else:
        # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< why this never happens!?
        logger.debug("db_context acquired from thread local")

    return db_context


app = Flask(__name__)
... more initialization

@app.before_request
def open_db_connection():
    """
    Ensures that the database connection has been created and made
    available under the thread local bound store
    """
    thread_id = threading.get_ident()
    logger.warning(f"BEFORE REQUEST ({thread_id}): initializing database connection ...")
    db_context = db_context_factory()
    assert db_context.is_open(), "database connection must be open at this point"
    logger.warning(f"BEFORE REQUEST ({thread_id}): initializing database connection done.")

@app.after_request
def close_db_connection(response):
    thread_id = threading.get_ident()
    logger.warning(f"AFTER REQUEST ({thread_id}): closing database connection ...")
    # should get the one that was created on the before request step
    db_context = db_context_factory()
    db_context.close()
    logger.warning(f"AFTER REQUEST ({thread_id}): closing database connection done.")

    thread_local = threading.local()
    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I get exception here because 'db_context' isn't in thread local
    delattr(thread_local, TL_DB_CONTEXT_KEY)
    return response
```